# How to extract data inside string?

Tags: c, string, extract

I have this string:

`('string1', 'string2', 'string3');`

I want to extract data ONLY the string1, string2, string3.

Have tried something like this:

```
scanf("%s", &data1);
printf("%s", data1);
if(d=='`')
{
    scanf("%s", &sampah);
    printf("%s", sampah);
    if(d=='`')
    {
        scanf("%s", &data2);
        printf("%s", data2);
        if(d=='`')
        {
            scanf("%s", &sampah);
            printf("%s", sampah);
            if(d=='`')
            {
                scanf("%s", &data3);
                printf("%s", data3);
                if(d=='`')
                {
                    scanf("%s", &sampah);
                    printf("%s", sampah);
                    if(d=='`')
                    {
                        scanf("%s", &data4);
                        printf("%s", data4);    
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep using `if(d=='\`')` ... what is `d`? How is it assigned a value?

Comment: What is `d`?  It's being checked at each stage, but it's never set.

Comment: You are searching for `'\`'` ever deeper, while `('string1', 'string2', 'string3')` don't seem to contain that character...

Comment: It takes less than two hours to figure this out from the `scanf` documentation or a good C book.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `strtok` with `'` as the delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char str[] = "('string1', 'string2', 'string3');";
    char s1[16], s2[16], s3[16], ch;

    if(3==sscanf(str, "( '%15[^']' , '%15[^']' , '%15[^']' ) ; %c", s1, s2, s3, &ch)){
        printf("'%s'\n", s1);
        printf("'%s'\n", s2);
        printf("'%s'\n", s3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me alot @BLUEPIXY ! It printed with quote. How if I just want to get the value inside the quotation mark?

Comment: @Kamil `puts(s1);` ?

Comment: AMAZING! Great Thanks. But Sorry I couldn't give upvote. Needs 15 reputation hehe

Answer (score 1):

You need simple finite-state machine with two states "inside quotes" and "outside quotes", with quotation mark transitioning between those two states.

Something like:

```
void tokenize(const char *str)
{
    const char *c = str;
    int in_quotes = 0;
    const char *start_of_token;

    while (*c) {                        // examine each character
        if (*c == '\'') {
            if (!in_quotes) {
                start_of_token = c + 1; // quoted string starts at character following the quote
                in_quotes = 1;
            } else {
                // here is the end of token. It starts at start_of_token
                // and is c-start_of_token characters long
                int token_length = c-start_of_token
                do_something(start_of_token, token_length);
                in_quotes = 0;
            }
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```